# Guardar datos de archivo de texto separados por ;

Tags: c

Mi pregunta es como puedo levantar los datos de un txt cuando estos están separados por `;`.

Ejemplo:

```
Nombre;Telefono;nacionalidad

Pablo Perez;41414545;Argentino
```

Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Lo primero sería saber lo que has intentado... Bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en Español :), date una vuelta por el [tour] y por [ask] para que tengas una mejor idea de como funciona este sitio ¡Y de paso te ganas tu primera medalla! Vale?

Comment: @Ale1398 edita la pregunta y muestra el codigo que tienes ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pregunta esta orientada al lenguaje de programación de C, por lo cual te recomiendo implementar una función llamada: split.

Te puedes orientar a partir del siguiente [código](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210528/split-string-with-delimiters-in-c) (Recuperado del usuario hmjd):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

char** str_split(char* a_str, const char a_delim)
{
    char** result    = 0;
    size_t count     = 0;
    char* tmp        = a_str;
    char* last_comma = 0;
    char delim[2];
    delim[0] = a_delim;
    delim[1] = 0;

    /* Count how many elements will be extracted. */
    while (*tmp)
    {
        if (a_delim == *tmp)
        {
            count++;
            last_comma = tmp;
        }
        tmp++;
    }

    /* Add space for trailing token. */
    count += last_comma < (a_str + strlen(a_str) - 1);

    /* Add space for terminating null string so caller
       knows where the list of returned strings ends. */
    count++;

    result = malloc(sizeof(char*) * count);

    if (result)
    {
        size_t idx  = 0;
        char* token = strtok(a_str, delim);

        while (token)
        {
            assert(idx < count);
            *(result + idx++) = strdup(token);
            token = strtok(0, delim);
        }
        assert(idx == count - 1);
        *(result + idx) = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Y posteriormente llamar dicha función cuando lo necesites, por ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
    char months[] = "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC";
    char** tokens;

    printf("months=[%s]\n\n", months);

    tokens = str_split(months, ',');

    if (tokens)
    {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; *(tokens + i); i++)
        {
            printf("month=[%s]\n", *(tokens + i));
            free(*(tokens + i));
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(tokens);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Los datos de entradas es el siguiente:

> **Cadena**: "JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC"
>
> **Delimitador**: ','

Y los datos de salidas son los siguientes:

> month=[JAN]
>
> month=[FEB]
>
> month=[MAR] **...**

Saludos, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero esperamos que el que haga la pregunta se esfuerce por tener un [mcve]